# Correct spelling of "program"

Tags: orthography

I mostly have exposure to American English online. I am currently writing out a resume and need some help.

In Australia, in general, we write *programme* to mean a schedule or community programme. However with computer studies I'm inclined to write *program* to mean a computer program rather than the proverbial programme.

What is the correct spelling?

Comment: "Program" if you are talking about a computer program is usually deemed acceptable in the UK.

Comment: Do IT literate speakers actually write "computer programme" at all? I thought the distinction was fairly clear: to a UK (IT literate) speaker, a "programme" and a "program" are simply different things.

Comment: Related fact: "dialog(ue)" is often/usually spelled with the "ue" in e.g. literature, but always without in "dialog box".

Comment: @NeilCoffey And what exactly is the difference? They are the same thing; whether or not as a matter of style one uses a specific spelling for a specific type of programme is another matter.

Comment: @Marcin As I say, to a computer-literate UK speaker I think they're "different things". In other words, say, a "Java program" and a "theatre programme" aren't subclasses of "the same type of thing".

Comment: @NeilCoffey That's pure assertion. On what basis do you draw a distinction?

Comment: Erm... on the basis that they're different things?!?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

We reference the *Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary*.

In British English, we write *television [programme](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/programme_1)* and *computer [program](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/program_1)*.

In American English, we write *television program* and *computer program*.

Comment: Agreed (from an Australian). Also Dialog refers to a pop up screen but dialogue refers to a two way communication. Catalogue is a list of items whereas catalog is a computerised list.

Comment: @Dave fully agree with you - from a New Zealander, which is close enough for this discussion

Comment: In BrE we can also write *computer programme*. I certainly do, and my dictionary agrees with me.

Comment: The Guardian newspaper's style guide agrees with this answer's British English usage: "program (computer); otherwise programme". http://www.guardian.co.uk/styleguide/p

Comment: In American English, the spelling is always *analog,* *catalog,* *dialog,* *program.* The dichotomy in Australia and Britain comes from using the American spelling for the meanings related to computers.

Comment: I'm another Australian who agrees. In the early days of computers people did write "computer programme" but by the time this sense settled into the national vocabulary the "program" spelling definitely emerged as the standard one.

Comment: I think the propensity of the use of program for computer program is an adoption of the US spelling because that is where the vast majority of early computing literature came from. I believe that both options are acceptable in all cases, but that 'computer programme' would be considered a bit quaint.

Comment: @dave: I've given you, and this answer, a +1, as an Australian, but I do still try to say dialogue box.

Comment: Now that @Clarkkent has edited his answer, it's no longer clear what the Australians and New Zealanders above are agreeing or disagreeing with.  However, it behooves me to point out that we New Zealanders write "TV programme" and "computer program".  FWIW, I have in my hand one edition of "The TV Guide", a New Zealand publication whose front page has the words "Programmes June 2-8".

Answer (score 11):

In British (real) English *programme* is used in general, except in terms of computer programming, and related activities where the American form *program* is used.

> A: Can you program the video recorder
>   for me?
>
> B: Sure, what programme do you
>   wish to record?

Comment: +1 for defining British as "Real" English.  Kind of hard to dispute ;-)

Answer (score 8):

I've mostly been exposed to American English myself; however, that said, when I've read articles in British magazines they seem to use "program" when referring to computer programs. Likewise, here's a blog entry that seems to back me up: [Program vs. Programme](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/get-with-the-programme/).

Answer (score 3):

There's no good reason to draw a distinction between a computer programme and any other programme. For that reason, I always write "programme". I seem to be in the minority, though.

Comment: You're right. It is not really necessary to have such a distinction. It seems to me that people who do so are probably ignorant of differences in American English or, are just copying American English, because of personal preference or just because other people are.

Comment: It's a long time since *programme* was a reasonable analogy for what computer programs do.

Comment: @JonHanna Hot take: you're wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As a computer programmer, writing a computer programme is wrong. It might be acceptable linguistically, but in terms of communications, it is always program. And it does come from the American version, but is part of British English now.

"Quaint" is the polite version of what impression programme gives.

Comment: Seeing *þᵉ olde computator programme* certainly does leave one with a … ‘quaint’ impression.

Comment: There is simply no distinction between the referents of "programme" and "program". They are the very same thing.