# Should I use 'program' or 'programme'?

Tags: grammar

I'm in the process of translating a text from French to English and I was wondering how to use the variants of the word *program* / *programme*.

A few friends have said to me that I should render it 'programme' but my own experience tells me it should be 'program'.

Who should I trust?

Here's an example where it's used :

> The first few times you use the program, it may take you a little
>   longer. Repeat the program until you fall asleep.

Thanks a lot

Comment: To sum it up, AmE = "program", BrE = computer -> "program", everywhere else -> "programme". As for the verb, double "m" is mostly used, but sometimes, however rarely a single "m" is accepted in AmE.

Comment: This can be looked up in a dictionary of your choice.

Comment: I've corrected and tweaked your post. You may want to compare it with the original.

Comment: Duplicate of [Correct spelling of “program”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7855/correct-spelling-of-program).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few different meanings of "programme/program":

> 1) computer software which can be run - "program" everywhere
>
> 2) a tv show - "programme" in the uk and "program" everwhere else
>
> 3) a scheduled or defined set of activities, eg exercise:  in the uk, sometimes (more increasingly I think) "program" but more officially "programme".  "Program" everywhere else.

In your case it sounds like definition 3, so it depends on your audience to some extent, but I think you could use "program" without causing any problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear information.

It is indeed definition 3 ! I'm gonna stick to "program" then.

Thanks again for answering my question that fast. You guys are really helpful.

Comment: Where is this quote from? Always attribute all quotes.