# What is the spelling of program/programme

Tags: american-english, british-english

Do you say program or programme? Which one is original english? Which one should we use?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. See *[Correct spelling of "program"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7855/correct-spelling-of-program)*; in brief, *programme* is not used in American English.

Comment: Thank you! I am enjoying EL&U. Even though I did not sign myself up.

Answer (score 0):

Acording to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/programme), *programme* is the British spelling and you can therefore assume that *program* is the American spelling.

[image: Wiktionary]

Also, according to [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=program%2C%20programme&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprogram%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprogramme%3B%2Cc0), *programme* was originally the most common spelling but was then overtaken by *program* in around 1913.

[image: Google Ngram]

As for which one you "should" use, well, do as you wish. I personally like to use archaic words that aren't spoken often anymore so I'd say go with *programme* if you're asking me.

Comment: No, it's not that simple. Please see the duplicate thread I linked.